# save reinforcement learning model

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to reinforcement learning and I have implemented a simple q-learning model using just Numpy. So I would like to know how I can save the model to use it later, and also I want to know how I can use it later, i.e, how do I use it for evaluation?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Q-learning models are simple tables!
Therefore, you could use something like pickle to save your object in a file, and then load it the next time you need to use it.

```
import pickle
with open("qtable.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(q_table, f)
```

to save your model.

To retrieve your model then use

```
with open("qtable.pickle", "rb") as f:
    q_table = pickle.load(f)
```